# How to use Jot Form with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, embed, jotform

I'm trying to embed a script tag to render a form in a component.  I can't figure out how to do this in React.  If I took this tag and pasted it to an HTML document, the form would load perfectly, but I don't know how to do the equivalent with React.

I cant paste the actual code to embed on this site for work reasons, but I'm basically trying to embed this into a component so that a form renders and users can submit the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/1234566789"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  tag

```js
   const styles = {} // if you want to add some custom CSS
   const URL = "https://form.jotform.com/jsform/1234566789" //embed URL

   <iframe title="your title" style={styles} src={URL}></iframe>
```

read more about it [HERE](https://www.riddle.com/docs/code-examples/custom-embed-code-for-react-js/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that just shows up as a box you can scroll to with all the code for the actual form inside of it- at least how I'm trying it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a lot easier than the solutions above and I couldn't find anything anywhere telling me how to do it. So, here's what I did:

1. Go to your form and the "Publish" page.
2. Select iframe and copy the code.
3. Create a file in the `public/` folder called "jotform-embed.htm" (or whatever you want to call it) and paste all of the iframe code into it.
4. Inside your React JSX, reference the file like this:

```js
<iframe
   title="Form Name"
   src="jotform-embed.htm"
   style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '750px',
   }}
/>
```

And that's all you have to do!

Answer (score 0):

I found a lovely node package that lets you embed Jotforms; you can find the NPM article here :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jotform-embed

Answer (score 0):

I made a component to easily embed JotForm.com forms to your ReactJS based websites or applications. It supports NextJS / Gatsby like SSR frameworks.

You also have access to some callbacks like onSubmit if you need.

You can access it here: https://npmjs.com/package/jotform-react